# unknow attribute in a file created from selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

i created a little script with selenium recorder and i exported it to a c# file,
selenium created so many code lines on it but some attributes like:

```
   [TestFixture]
    public class TestinGSelenium
    {
        private IWebDriver driver;
        private StringBuilder verificationErrors;
        private string baseURL;
        private bool acceptNextAlert = true;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetupTest()
        {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            baseURL = "http://www.google.it/";
            verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void TeardownTest()
        {
            try
            {
                driver.Quit();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // Ignore errors if unable to close the browser
            }
            NUnit.Core.NUnitFramework.Assert.AreEqual("", verificationErrors.ToString());
        }
```

visual studio cannot  verify attributes 
about :[TestFixture]    [TearDown]   [SetUp]
i added a reference to: "NUnit" and "selenium" but continues to return error .
what else can i do? to run this c# script?

thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Adding a reference is not enough.

You will also need to add a `using` for `NUnit.Framework` and `OpenQA.Selenium` and `OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox`:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using NUnit.Framework;
```

As you are using Visual Studio, it also has a handy tip - right-click on one of the attributes it is complaining about, and it will give you a quick handy option to add the reference & `using` on your behalf.

Comment: no, not working yet
i added all of this

using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Selenium;
using NUnit.Core.NUnitFramework.Assert;
using NUnit.Core.NUnitFramework;

Comment: What does `not working` mean? What is the *full* error message and stack trace **you are now getting**?